# Get-ChildItem Array does not work as expected

Tags: arrays, powershell

I found a script I would like to use to find all the subfolders in a folder and report when they were last accessed, as well as their size.  I hope this hasn't been asked before!  I am using Powershell v3 on a Win 7 machine.
This is the code:

```
$results=@()
$folders = Get-ChildItem | where {$_.psiscontainer}
foreach ($folder in $folders) 
{
    $Size = (Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | Measure-Object -property Length -Sum).sum / 1KB 
    $results += Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, LastAccessTime, @{Name="Day's Since Access";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days)}}, @{Name="Size in MB";Expression={$Size}}    
}
$results | sort LastAccessTime | ft -AutoSize
```

The output I'm getting lists ALL the files in the folder while displaying the size of the subfolders over and over again.  The output I'm getting looks like this:

> Name                                       LastAccessTime         Day's Since Access   Size in MB
>   ----                                       --------------         ------------------   ----------
>   Get-ServicePacks.txt                       4/17/2014 5:16:13 PM                    4    290.09375
>   Get-ServicePacks.txt                       4/17/2014 5:16:13 PM                    4    121.46875
>   Get-ServicePacks.txt                       4/17/2014 5:16:13 PM                    4 196.87890625
>   Get-LatestFile.txt                         4/21/2014 12:26:45 PM                   1    121.46875
>   Get-LatestFile.txt                         4/21/2014 12:26:45 PM                   1    290.09375
>   Get-LatestFile.txt                         4/21/2014 12:26:45 PM                   1 196.87890625
>   Get-LatestFile.ps1                         4/21/2014 12:27:53 PM                   1    290.09375
>   Get-LatestFile.ps1                         4/21/2014 12:27:53 PM                   1 196.87890625
>   Get-LatestFile.ps1                         4/21/2014 12:27:53 PM                   1    121.46875

What I was expecting was this:

> Name                                       LastAccessTime         Day's Since Access   Size in MB
>   ----                                       --------------         ------------------   ----------
>   Display-Computers-Status-and-info-with-Gui 4/17/2014 5:16:13 PM                    4    290.09375
>   GetSpecifiedFileExtension 4/21/2014 12:26:45 PM                   1 196.87890625
>   HOTFIXES4/21/2014 12:27:53 PM                   1    121.46875

I want to format the output so I get the size of the folder along with the Name and the Last Accessed Date.  I would really appreciate it if someone could explain why my attempt at coding is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to reference the `$Folder` instead of getting the contents of the folder for your `$results =+` line. Try changing it to this:

```
$results += $folder | Select-Object Name, LastAccessTime, @{Name="Day's Since Access";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.LastAccessTime).Days)}}, @{Name="Size in MB";Expression={$Size}}
```